# Error relating another make utility in one system

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, mingw, gnu

I have google how to install a gnu make file. And I follow the following steps:
   $ ./configure
   $ sh ./build.sh
   $ ./make check

**Unfortunately when I run the second command, my cygwin shell complains:**

In file included from c:\qt\tools\mingw48_32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\sys\stat.h                                                   :14:0,
                 from ./makeint.h:71,
                 from ./ar.c:18:
./makeint.h:525:10: error: conflicting types for 'lseek64'
 long int lseek ();

I am aware there is another make utility under the qt mingw, but how can i still proceed to install the new make?

Comment: That's not a make error that's a compilation error. What version of make do you have installed now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source distribution of GNU make from the FSF download site is not technically supported on Cygwin.  Not that there's any known reason why it shouldn't work, but it's not tested and last I heard the Cygwin guys were maintaining some extra patches to GNU make.  So it doesn't surprise me that there are issues.

Remember that you should *only* use the Cygwin version of GNU make if you're invoking make inside of Cygwin to build Cygwin applications.  You should *not* use the Cygwin version of GNU make to build native Windows content outside of Cygwin.  Do not mix them together.

You can build a native version of GNU make for Windows (not cygwin) by following the directions in the README.W32 file that comes with the source code.  You can get binary versions by looking for MSYS / MinGW.

If you need a Cygwin version of GNU make, you should get ahold of the source code for GNU make from the Cygwin distribution and use that.  If it fails to work, you need to communicate with the Cygwin folks about it.

Comment: It seems like I have some confusion about “install” make. What I am trying to do is to use cygwin to configure and install the gdb-7.7 to replace the old gdb version exists in my qtCreator. Unfortunately the make utility in my system is complaining not recognizing some of the commands in the script. That's why I try to install a GNU make. Am I doing something wrong?